# How to compare between two numbers (twice) and return a string in XQuery

Tags: xquery, basex

I have a pub database and I need to compare two numbers (latitude) and two more (longitude), and return every pub name that is located between those coordinates.

I tried a where clause using both logical and arithmetic operators, tried with one variable and two variables.

Output is always the same all pubs, regardless the coordinates.

```
for $x in db:open("pub", "pub.xml")/serviceList/service
where $x/geoData/latitude='40.400000000000' and $x/geoData/latitude='40.410000000000'
return $x/basicData/name
```

The idea is to loop the database find all the pubs whose coordinates are between 40.40 and 40.41 (latitude) and -3.7 i -3.71 (longitude) and return the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently testing whether the latitude value is equal to two different strings with `and` criteria (it will never match both values unless there are more than one latitude elements, but you haven't shown an example of the XML)

You probably want to compare those latitude and longitude values as numbers (remove the quotes from your values)

```
for $x in db:open("pub", "pub.xml")/serviceList/service
where (
  $x/geoData/latitude >= 40.4 and $x/geoData/latitude <= 40.41
  and 
  $x/geoData/longitude >= -3.7 and $x/geoData/latitude <= 3.7
)
return $x/basicData/name
```

Comment: Really appreciated, but is not working, at least for me. Error: Types xs:untypedAtomic and xs:decimal are not comparable. After typing this post, I kept trying until I eventually got it working with the next code: ```for $x in db:open("pub", "pub.xml")/serviceList/service
let $lat := $x/geoData/latitude
let $lon := $x/geoData/longitude
where ($lat >= '40.40' and $lat <= '40.41') and $lon >= "-3.70" and ($lon <= "-3.71")
return <pub><nom>{data($x/basicData/name)}"</nom><coordinates>{data($x/geoData/latitude)}, {data($x/geoData/longitude)}</coordinates></pub>
 ```

Comment: @Rex, if you write XQuery code and want to use numbers then don't use string literals, so use `40.40` and not `'40.40'`, use `-3.70` (or simply `-3.7`) and not `"-3.70"`. As for Mads' suggestion, it would work with typed/validated XML where `latidude` where of a numeric type but in general it is easier to simply use the generic comparison operators `<` or `>` or `<=` or `>=` as they work with operands of different types like for instance the `xs:untypedAtomic`. So using `$x/geoData/latitude >= 40.4 and $x/geoData/latitude <= 40.41` is the right way and certainly doesn't give the error you get.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I gotta work with the xml I was given, is pretty much all strings. I do appreciate the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Mads Hansen can be abbreviated to:

```
for $x in db:open("pub", "pub.xml")/serviceList/service
where (
  $x/geoData/latitude[. ge 40.4 and . le 40.41]
  and 
  $x/geoData/longitude[. ge -3.7 and . le 3.7]
)
return $x/basicData/name
```

or even further to

```
db:open("pub", "pub.xml")/serviceList/service
    [geoData[latitude[. ge 40.4 and . le 40.41] and longitude[. ge -3.7 and . le 3.7]]
    /basicData/name
```